# How to create max method that gets 4 numbers and returns the maximum number?

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers, return, max

I'm trying to build a method that would get 4 numbers and returns the maximum number of them.

I tried to write this code that gets 4 numbers but this not working:

Input and output:

```
double a = Math.max(10, 5, 4, 3);
    System.out.println(a);

public static int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d)
        return a;
    if (b > a && b > c && b > d)
        return b;
    if (c > a && c > b && c > d)
        return c;
    if (d > b && d > c && d > a)
        return d;
}
```

Comment: use `Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(a,b),Math.max(c,d)))`

Comment: you can use an `int[]` instead of 4 `int`s also

Comment: What if two elements are both greatest? I suppose that `max(2, 3, 4, 4)` should be 4, but how would your code be supposed to get to that result?

Comment: Please (have you been told this before?) be more specific. “Not working” is not a problem description. You need to tell us exactly what your code does that differs from the desired. You also need to quote any error messages exactly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would simplify this by introducing a variable `max`:

```
public static int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

    int max = a;

    if (b > max)
        max = b;
    if (c > max)
        max = c;
    if (d > max)
        max = d;

     return max;
}
```

You could also use [`Math.max`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_max_int.htm), as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293080/how-to-create-max-method-that-gets-4-numbers-and-returns-the-maximum-number/27293146#comment43051356_27293080) by [fast snail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227526/fast-snail), but since this seems to be homework, I would prefer the algorithmic solution.

```
Math.max(Math.max(a,b),Math.max(c,d))
```

Comment: Patrick, I had expected you to be too experienced on Stackoverflow to solve people’s homework assignments for them. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try `Math.max` like below:

```
return Math.max(Math.max(a, b), Math.max(c, d));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a method like this which will work as you wanted for any number of integers:

```
public static Integer max(Integer... vals) {
    return new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(vals)).last();
}
```

Call, for example, as:

```
System.out.println(max(10, 5, 17, 4, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int max(Integer... vals) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(vals));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c > a && c > b && c > d)
    return d;
```

here you are returning d instead of c.

Comment: Add more description so that other can understand

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it...

```
public static int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d)
        return a;
    if (b > c && b > d)
        return b;
    if (c > d)
        return c;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Integer max(Integer... values)
{
     Integer maxValue = null
     for(Integer value : values)
         if(maxValue == null || maxValue < value)
              maxValue = value;
     return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: This trumps other suggestions for (a) handling any number of values and (b) accepting an array of values as input too, makes this far more flexible than a method accepting exactly four integers.

Comment: What about memory performance? Unnecessary varargs array creation and unnecessary boxing. Neither what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int max(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        return (a>b && a>c && a>d? a: b>c && b>d? b: c>d? c:d);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

   int tmp1 = a > b ? a : b;
   int tmp2 = c > d ? c : d;

   return tmp1 > tmp2 ? tmp1 : tmp2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int max(int... p)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i : p) {
        max = i > max ? i : max; 
    }
    return max;

}
```